# Jquery: Selecting element OR variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have looked for an answer to this but the answers I have found don't seem to solve my issue.

I want to get the same functionality as this:

```
$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products"), .dropdown.productmenu').hover(function(){
    showThis.call($(productMenu));
}, function(){
    hideThis.call($(productMenu));
});
```

By instead using a variable for the second selector, something like below:

```
var productMenu = $('.dropdown.productmenu');

$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")', productMenu).hover(function(){
    showThis.call($(productMenu));
}, function(){
    hideThis.call($(productMenu));
});
```

productMenu is a slide-on-hover menu that should appear - and does with the first example. But I can't get it to work with the second one. How would I select '.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")' OR the variable called productMenu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")', productMenu)` is the same as `productMenu.find('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products"), .dropdown.productmenu').hover(function(){
```

is the same as

```
$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")').hover(function(){...

$('.dropdown.productmenu').hover(function(){...
```

or perhaps more precisely

```
$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")')
.add('.dropdown.productmenu').hover(function(){...
```

whereas

```
$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")', productMenu).hover...
```

is the same as

```
productMenu.find('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")').hover...
```

which means it is a child element of `productMenu`

**USE THIS**

```
$('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")')
.add(productMenu).hover(function(){...
```

or `productMenu.add('.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")').hover(function(){...`

Comment: thanks a lot Mark. Does this mean that the conventional $('x, x, x') multiple element selector won't work when variables are required to be selected rather than just HTML elements?

Comment: Those are within that same string and you would have to concatenate strings held in a variable with commas to make that work.  Easier to simply do the `.add` on them instead, OR put them in an array and then use something like `var myVar2 = a.join(', ');` where `a` is the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understanding your question, however if `'.navlistitem > a:contains("Products")'` is not a descendant of `'.dropdown.productmenu'`, the second won't work.

The second parameter is to set the "context" of the call for the selector.

Comment: hi ry4nolson, thanks for the reply. Basically, I want to select both 'navlistitem > a:contains("Products")' (so if the menu item 'products' is hovered on, the dropdown will show) and the dropdown productMenu itself (so if the mouse moves away from the 'products' menu item and onto the dropdown menu, it will stay down rather than slide up again). What I don't know is how I can select both of these, given that one is a direct jQuery element selection and one is a variable